# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'kty' in jose-simple

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got error when I using `jose-simple` package:

```
(node:20128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'kty' in -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgGn5jHGyp8qbpDb7L1+yWrO6cdGn
t3oMXZuOVXENSOXFJJR2vvwwfBZjxtaazuWBKseSW/YJt162l7XuAZbgTq1kbSAv
8PwpqYUc1rkDhlLg2lMbsKs6TSScIhCFiNUb1RTdBu82o0QF9+hhlZ2rpdF3HMWm
9GJfPGngoqwn/QV5AgMBAAE=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    at C:\xxx\node_modules\node-jose\lib\jwe\encrypt.js:576:20
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

The private and public key I generate from: http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/

How to solve this error?

app.js:

```
const jose = require('jose-simple');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './private.key'), 'utf-8');

const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './public.key'), 'utf-8');

const { encrypt, decrypt } = jose(privateKey, publicKey)

const someData = {
  some: 'amazing data',
  you: 'want to keep hidden',
  from: 'prying eyes'
}

encrypt(someData).then(encrypted => {
  console.log('encrypted', encrypted)
  decrypt(encrypted).then(decrypted => {
    console.log('decrypted', decrypted)
    // decrypted will be the same as someData
  })
})
```

public.key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgGn5jHGyp8qbpDb7L1+yWrO6cdGn
t3oMXZuOVXENSOXFJJR2vvwwfBZjxtaazuWBKseSW/YJt162l7XuAZbgTq1kbSAv
8PwpqYUc1rkDhlLg2lMbsKs6TSScIhCFiNUb1RTdBu82o0QF9+hhlZ2rpdF3HMWm
9GJfPGngoqwn/QV5AgMBAAE=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```